# JSF combo box change to default value

Tags: java, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, combobox

I have an JSF application in which I have a combo box. Based the that combo box value I want to change other two combo boxes value.

```
<h:outputText value="#{msgs.transformation_rule}"/>
      <h:panelGroup>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="dsTransformationRule" value="#{activityDataSource.selectedTransformationRule}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{activityDataSource.transformationRules}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <ui:fragment rendered="#{sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageRules')}" >
              <input type="button" value="#{msgs.button_ellipsis}" class="ruleEditorBtn"
                     onclick="SailPoint.Rule.Editor.edit($('editForm:dsTransformationRule').value,
                             'ActivityTransformer',
                             $('editForm:refreshActivityDataSourceRulesButton'))" />
          </ui:fragment>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:outputText value="#{msgs.correlation_rule}"/>
      <h:panelGroup>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="dsCorrelationRule" value="#{activityDataSource.selectedCorrelationRule}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}">
            <f:selectItems value="#{activityDataSource.correlationRules}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <ui:fragment rendered="#{sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageRules')}" >
              <input type="button" value="#{msgs.button_ellipsis}" class="ruleEditorBtn"
                     onclick="SailPoint.Rule.Editor.edit($('editForm:dsCorrelationRule').value,
                             'ActivityCorrelation',
                             $('editForm:refreshActivityDataSourceRulesButton'))" />
          </ui:fragment>
      </h:panelGroup>

      <h:outputText value="#{msgs.activity_data_src_type}"/>
      <h:panelGroup>
        <a4j:outputPanel id="collectorSettings">
          <h:selectOneMenu id="collectorType"
                           value="#{activityDataSource.object.type}"
                           rendered="#{empty activityDataSource.object.id}"
                           disabled="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           readonly="#{!sp:hasRight(facesContext, 'ManageApplication')}"
                           onchange="$('editForm:selectTypeButton').click();">
             <f:ajax event="change" 
                    execute="@this" 
                    render="dsTransformationRule dsCorrelationRule"
                    listener="#{activityDataSource.handleCollectorTypeChange}" />
            <f:selectItem itemValue="" itemLabel="#{msgs.select_collector_type}"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{activityDataSource.collectorTypes}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
          <h:selectOneMenu id="fixedCollectorType" value="#{empty activityDataSource.object.type ? 'None' : activityDataSource.object.type}"
                           rendered="#{not empty activityDataSource.object.id}"
                           disabled="true"
                           readonly="true">
            <f:selectItem itemValue="#{empty activityDataSource.object.type ? 'None' : activityDataSource.object.type}"
                          itemLabel="#{empty activityDataSource.object.type ? msgs.none : activityDataSource.object.type}"/>
          </h:selectOneMenu>
        </a4j:outputPanel>
```

```
<a4j:commandButton id="selectTypeButton" action="#{activityDataSource.selectType}" style="display:none"
                       render="configSettings, collectorSettings"
                       oncomplete="initializeSelectedConfigPage();"/>
```

Now problem is that I am not able to understand

```
onchange="$('editForm:selectTypeButton').click();">
```

I have written ajax part for change event for `collectorType` in which I am changing value of other two combo boxes.
Also I want that for one value in `collectorType` the other two combo box should change to default text like '**Select collector type**'. How can I do this.

Also ajax event is firing before normal change event.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same principle for Richfaces as Primefaces. Your ajax call should update the other backing beans current value

This ajax call will update the current Club.

```
<p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{serviceHCP.getClubs(player)

serviceHCP.myCurrentClub // Will be set and used in the next menu.

<p:selectOneMenu value="#{player}"
                converter="playerConverter" id="playerList">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" noSelectionOption="true" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{servicePlayer.allPlayers}"
             var="n"
             itemValue="#{n}"
             itemLabel="#{n.combinedName}"
             itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
              <p:ajax event="change" execute="@this" listener="#{serviceHCP.getClubs(player) }" update="clubMenu" render="clubMenu"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>

            <h:outputText value="Klubb"></h:outputText>
               <p:selectOneMenu value="#{serviceHCP.myCurrentClub}" converter="clubConverter" id="clubMenu" >
                    <f:selectItem itemLabel="---" noSelectionOption="true" />
                    <f:selectItems value="#{serviceHCP.myClubList}"
                 var="clb"
                 itemValue="#{clb}"
                 itemLabel="#{clb.name}"
                 itemLabelEscaped="true"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Could you tell me the meaning of this line. onchange="$('editForm:selectTypeButton').click();">

Comment: it seems to simulate a click on the button.